# Calculating moments of inertia for partially filled cylinders

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, moment-of-inertia

I'm planning on doing an experiment with cylinders of equal length and constant density but different solid fills. For example, a filled cylinder, $75\%$ filled, $50\%$ filled, $25\%$ filled, and a hollow cylinder.

I will need the moment of inertia for each of these objects. Is it possible to calculate or find a source for moment of inertia based on partial fills?

Some example values: $density = 1.2g/cm^3$, $length = 10cm$, $radius = 3cm$

Comment: Does the fill move and can it slosh around?

Comment: @SolarMike no it's a solid

Comment: @Triatticus it's an even solid distribution but I'm not sure what you mean by rotated. It spins down a ramp with its long side down if that helps.

Comment: Indeed it helps as the moment of inertia depends on the axis about which the mass is distributed and rotated

Comment: Hi TNTCookie. Welcome to Phys.SE. If you haven't already done so, please take a minute to read the definition of when to use the [homework-and-exercises](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/homework-and-exercises/info) tag, and the Phys.SE [policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714) for homework-like problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I am assuming by partially filled you mean the mass density is uniform between an inner and outer radius, i.e. the cylinders are obtained by "carving out" a narrower coaxial cylinder from a uniform, filled cylinder.

The moment of inertia with respect to the axis of symmetry can be found by evaluating 
$$\iiint\limits_V{\rho r^2 dV},$$
where $\rho$ is the mass density and $r$ is the distance from the axis.

For the cylinders in question, this integral gives
$$I_{CM} = \frac{1}{2}MR^2\left[1 + (1-f)^2\right]$$
where $M$ is the total mass, $R$ is the outer radius and $f$ is the fraction of the cylinder filled. In terms of mass density, this is equal to
$$I_{CM} = \frac{1}{2}\pi\rho hR^4\left[1 - (1 - f)^4\right]$$

where $h$ is the height.

However, you indicated that the cylinders are rolling down a ramp. Assuming no slipping, the instantaneous axis of rotation of such a cylinder is the one in contact with the ramp. If you wish to calculate the moment of inertia with respect to this axis, according to the parallel axis theorem,
$$I = I_{CM} + MR^2.$$

Edit: What you may have meant by "partial fill" could simply be an effective decrease of $\rho$. If this is the case, just set $f=1$ in the above equations, and replace $\rho$ by $f\rho$.

Comment: You are correct about the 'carving out' but thanks for the extension too. This looks good but what's the difference between I and I_CM? I'm pretty sure I need I_CM for my calculation.

Comment: $I_{CM}$ is the moment of inertia about the axis of symmetry, and $I$ is the moment of inertia about a parallel axis a distance $R$ away (passing through the outer surface of the cylinder).